# Preventing users from merging a forked project into the original project in Azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops

I've forked a project in Azure DevOps, and I want to implement a measure to prevent users from merging changes directly from the forked project into the original project. My goal is to maintain a clear separation between the forked and original projects to avoid accidental or unauthorized merges.

Is there a recommended approach or best practice in Azure DevOps for preventing merges from a forked project into the original project? Or are there specific settings or configurations I might be overlooking?

We have implemented pull request approval process (4 eye principle)

Comment: You have branch policies enforcing PRs? Then... don't approve merges that come from a fork.

Comment: You could use an automated test in your CI-pipeline that checks this. Maybe based on version numbering, git history...

Comment: Hi @Mek.Dingi, have you got a chance to check my answer below? It can work with the branch policy of `Build Validation` to abandon the pull request from fork repo automatically. You may consider accepting it which may also help other community members with similar requirement. Thx.

Comment: Hi @Mek.Dingi, May I know if the suggestion below may help resolve your query? If the answer is helpful, would you [accept it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235), which may benefit others with related concerns. Thx.

Answer (score 1):

As of now, there is no such feature out of the box to automatically detect if the source branch of a PR is from a fork repo and abandon the PR.

Based on your requirement, I have tested and managed to use `Build Validation` feature of the branch policy to setup a pipeline triggered by the creation of a PR, which can detect if the source branch of the PR is from a fork repo by evaluating the value of the [predefined variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) `System.PullRequest.IsFork` and abandon the PR with the [API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/pull-requests/update?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1#gitpullrequestcompletionoptions). Here is a sample for your reference.

1. Create a YAML pipeline(`CheckForkRepo`) in the `main` branch of my protected repo;

   ```
   trigger: none

   pool:
     vmImage: ubuntu-latest

   variables:
     system.debug: true
     AzureDevOpsOrgName: xxMyDevOpsOrgNamexx
     TheProjectName: TheProjectName
     TheRepoName: TheRepoName

   jobs:
   - job:
     steps:
     - powershell: |
         Write-Host The source branch is from a fork repo - $(System.PullRequest.IsFork)
         Write-Host The triggering PR Id is $(System.PullRequest.PullRequestId)
         $URL = "https://dev.azure.com/$(AzureDevOpsOrgName)/$(TheProjectName)/_apis/git/repositories/$(TheRepoName)/pullrequests/$(System.PullRequest.PullRequestId)?api-version=7.1-preview.1"
         $header = @{
         'Authorization' = 'bearer ' + '$(System.AccessToken)'
         'Content-Type' = 'application/json'
         }
         $body = @"
         {
           "status": "abandoned"
         }
         "@
         Invoke-RestMethod -Method Patch -Uri $URL -Headers $header -Body $body | ConvertTo-Json
       condition: eq( variables['System.PullRequest.IsFork'], 'true' )
   ```
2. Add `Build Validation` policy for the protected branch `main` with the pipeline just created;
   [image]
3. Make sure the **corresponding** pipeline build service account has the permission to `Contribute to pull requests` according to your job authorization scope;
   [image]
4. Whenever a PR is created and targeting the `main` branch in my protected repo, the pipeline will be triggered by this PR and the variable `System.PullRequest.PullRequestId` is also passed in the script; if the source branch of the PR is from a fork repo, the variable `System.PullRequest.IsFork` will output `True`, and thus, the `PowerShell` scipt will then abandon this PR; if the source branch of the PR is not from a fork repo, the variable `System.PullRequest.IsFork` will output `False` and the `PowerShell` task will be skipped.
   [image]
5. If you would prefer, you may also use an agentless job to call the same API;

   ```
   trigger: none

   pool:
     vmImage: ubuntu-latest

   variables:
     system.debug: true
     AzureDevOpsOrgName: xxMyDevOpsOrgNamexx
     TheProjectName: TheProjectName
     TheRepoName: TheRepoName

   jobs:
   - job: 
     pool: server
     condition: and( eq(variables['Build.Reason'], 'PullRequest'), eq(variables['System.PullRequest.IsFork'], 'true') )
     steps:
     - task: InvokeRESTAPI@1
       inputs:
         connectionType: 'connectedServiceName'
         serviceConnection: 'AzureDevOpsServices'
         method: 'PATCH'
         headers: |
           {
           "Content-Type": "application/json",  
           "Authorization": "bearer $(System.AccessToken)"
           }
         body: |
           {
           "status": "abandoned"
           }
         urlSuffix: '/$(AzureDevOpsOrgName)/$(TheProjectName)/_apis/git/repositories/$(TheRepoName)/pullrequests/$(System.PullRequest.PullRequestId)?api-version=7.1-preview.1'
         waitForCompletion: 'false'
   ```

As suggested by @Daniel Mann, you may consider adding branch policy with required reviewers to manually reject unexpected PRs or disabling the `Forks` of your repo at the very beginning.

[image]

Hope the suggestions would help.

Comment: It's too bad OP never came back. This should have gotten the checkmark. ;)

Comment: Thanks @TTT. Glad to know the answer can provide some useful information. Well, it doesn't matter since I still learnt a lot during the test and there may be such a built-in function someday. Happy coding and cheers!